# Bulk INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE inserts only a small fraction of rows in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update, duplication, bulk-insert

I have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `demo_upsert` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Url` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `LastListID` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Statistics` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `Url` (`Url`) USING HASH
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

When I try a bulk upsert operation:

```
INSERT INTO demo_upsert (Url, LastListID) VALUES (?, 9)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LastListID=9
```

Out of ~15K rows for insert, I'm getting ~200 rows actually affected. The latter number depends on the previous number of rows in `demo_upsert` table.

The MariaDB versions tried are `10.4.12` and `10.4.13` - same problem.

UPDATE: I've implemented a reproducer program and submitted a bug https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONC-472

Comment: *Out of ~15K rows for insert, I'm getting ~200 rows actually affected.* Affected == which's values were really changed, i.e. only those duplicates which's old `LastListID` value was NOT `9`.

Comment: @Akina, according to the documentation, MariaDB/MySQL must report each inserted row as 1 and each updated row as 2. So if rows are updated rather than inserted, the number must be even larger.

Comment: I cannot say anything about MariaDB - I have no it on my comp now. But MySQL reports 4 different numbers during `INSERT .. ODKU`, like: *Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.10 sec) Records: 4  Duplicates: 2  Warnings: 0*. What number you tell about?

Comment: @Akina, I mean the number reported by `mysql_affected_rows()` from Connector/C.